# Matching multiple strings in R/nlp/spacyr

Tags: r, nlp, spacy, string-matching

I have a data frame

```
myDataframe <- data.frame(keyword = c(c("meeting", "laptop"),c("attend a meeting", "fan")))
description <- "I have to attend a meeting."
```

I have to match the description with the column keyword in the dataframe and return "attend a meeting".
Is there any solution to get a particular output

Comment: Is `description` is character vector

Comment: sorry, It's a text. description = "I have to attend a meeting."

Comment: I recommend you to learn * tidytext* for text wrangling [Introduction to tidytext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grepl` will return the keywords in `myDataframe` which contains in `description`

```r
myDataframe <- data.frame(keyword = c(c("meeting", "laptop"),c("attend a meeting", "fan")))
description <- "I have to attend a meeting."

found <- as.logical(lapply(myDataframe$keyword ,
                       function(x) grepl(x , description)))

myDataframe[found , ]
#> [1] "meeting"          "attend a meeting"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>